# [__NSCFString setView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8292720

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, uisearchdisplaycontroller, nscfstring

I have searchBar and searchDisplayController put in tabbar that is main tabbar.
When I open new viewcontroller by pushing there has no problem.

> mainTabbar -> navigationController+searchController -(push after
>   rowdidselect)-> newVC -(push)-> newVC -(push)-> ...

But when I do some present modal.

> mainTabbar -> navigationController+searchController -(push after
>   rowdidselect)-> newVC -(modal)-> newVC

Then back to searchResult

> mainTabbar -> navigationController+searchController

I can't push newViewController again and got these error:

```
[__NSCFString setView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8292720
```

what happening to me? all results just tell me about gesturecognizer.

::after I enable zombies I got this message

> -[UITapGestureRecognizer retain]:message sent to deallocated instance 0xfcd83b0

I guess the TapGestureRecognizer with in cell of searchDisplayController table is deallocated.
Anyone Know How to Retain them???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not really provide much info about your case, but in general the error log:

```
[__NSCFString setView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8292720
```

means that you are trying to send the `setView` message to the wrong object of type `NSString`.

Since you say that your code is working in one case, I assume this is not a problem with *you* sending the message to the wrong object. Rather, this is related to the proper object being deallocated, and its memory reused for an `NSString` object (which then receives the message).

I suspect the key might be with how you return back to search results, but you should provide more code for us to understand what is happening.

Comment: for modal I use dismissmodalViewController
for push-pop I use dismissViewController
to Close the ViewController

::after I enable zombies I got this message
-[UITapGestureRecognizer retain]:message sent to deallocated instance 0xfcd83b0

Comment: well, that confirms my hypothesis. could you show how and where you create the gesture recognizer? what I suppose is that your controller (containing the gesture recogniser) is deallocated, but the view attached to it remains there (it is not removed from its super view), so it keeps sending messages to the recogniser... but without seeing more code, I cannot say much more...

Comment: For push-pop why are you closing the viewcontroller with 'dismissViewController' instead 'popViewControllerAnimated:' ?

Comment: @RenoJones: +1, I completely oversaw that! that is surely wrong, although it seems that push/pop is working correctly for the OP...

Comment: RenoJones ok I will fix that now.
@sergio I'm not create any GestureRecognizer. I just use didSelectRowAtIndexpath and It crash after done everything in this method.

Comment: @RenoJones No Not Enjoy Yet. T^T The problem remain.
I guess my problem is when I call the modal view then the default gesture recognizers in tableview of searchDisplayController are deallocated. **But I don't know how to retain them**. Can I override them? or Can I set disable to them with didselectrowatindexpath still working? or else....

Comment: Hold on, It seems you are doing too much when a little is required: just modify your above post with the code you have got in 'didselectrowatindexpath'. Just post everything.

Comment: Solved : Problem is about IB gesture recognizer in newVC. 
I only move them from IB to code. the default gesture recognizer in cell of table in searchDisplayController is not available at all.